# Redirect all naked subfolders to subfoldername/public/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a `.htaccess` redirect/rewrite for all top level subfolders to a subfolder.

For example, my directory structure looks like this

```
/public_html

  /site1
    /public 

  /site2
    /public

  /site3
    /public
```

I would like anyone going to `example.com/site1/` to be served up the files from `example.com/site1/public`, but I don't want the URL to have to show `public`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule /(.?)/ /$1/public/ [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following instead in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(site1|site2|site3)/?(.*) /$1/public/$2 [L]
```

This targets any URL that *starts* `/site1`, `/site2` or `/site3` (note that in `.htaccess` the pattern excludes the slash prefix). And then internally rewrites the request from `/site1/<whatever>` to `/site1/public/<whatever>` using the `$1` and `$2` backreferences. The optional slash in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* ensures that it will also match a request for the bare subdirectory, excluding the trailing slash ie. `/site1`, rather than allowing mod_dir to first issue a redirect to `/site1/`.

To rewrite *any* root directory (not just limiting to `site1`, `site2`, etc.) then change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*) /$1/public/$2 [L]
```

The regex `[^/]+` matches just the first path segment, ie. everything excluding the first slash.

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we don't get a rewrite loop. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not set when the script is first called, but set to the HTTP status on the first rewrite (or error state).

> ```
> #RewriteRule /(.?)/ /$1/public/ [L]
> ```

A few problems with your original directive...

- `.?` only captures at most a single character - which you've made optional.
- `/(.?)/` would be matched *anywhere* in the requested URL (not at the start). But note that you can't match the first slash at the start of the URL-path anyway in a `.htaccess`/directory context (as mentioned above).
- You are not capturing the rest of the URL-path, so this would only rewrite to the document root, regardless of what URL was requested.
- This would trigger a rewrite loop. (Resulting in a 500 internal server error.)

Comment: here is something strange.  one of my sites `homebuyerNEW` rewrites to `domain.com/NEW` I think i just figured it out because it has the same name partial as another `homebuyer` after i changed the order that piece was fixed

Comment: If you have conflicts like that then you need to ensure that the most specific rules are first. Or you can make the slash (after the directory name) mandatory. eg. Remove the `?` in the regex to become: `^(site1|site2|site3)/(.*)`

Comment: my router on laravel is not recognizing the router now. Do i need to redirect as well?

Comment: Where is your router? Is this for a specific site, or all sites? What URL is your Laravel site expecting? If it's expecting to see `/site1/public/<whatever>` then yes, that has now changed so you will need to update the routing in your Laravel app (or adjust _how_ Laravel routes URLs)? Well, you could redirect - but that will expose the `public` subdirectory - all your URLs would then need to contain the `public` path segment (which is a different question to what you initially asked).